# Prevent Timeout for large scripts without changing any System Settings

Tags: php, ajax

## **Current Option**

If I have a process that I know may take a while I have been chopping it up using ajax to do a part of the request then once the ajax is returned do the next part of the request.

This is helpful because I can track percentage complete after each ajax returns but it relies on the browser sending the ajax requests, which may still timeout.

## New Option *Theory*

I think a better way is to let the server side code keep running the task without coming back to report to the GUI.

On the server side I have the script just run all tasks. It tracks its own run time and before max_execution_time is hit it spawns and another task (via cURL) and exits.

On the client side I run an interval every second or so checking the progress (minimal ajax script).

This would prevent the script from halting if the browser were to reload.

**To get the theory to work I have to answer the following questions:**

1. How can you check if the max execution time is near?
2. Is there a better way to accomplish this then cURL?
3. Can you even create a cURL request and end the script without waiting for the response or canceling the cURL?

The real question here is:

4. **How can you run a "process" that will run longer that the max execution time without changing max execution time?**

Comment: 1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php